# Canceling Membership Renewal Email

Tags: civimember

Two questions I'm hoping someone can help me answer:

1) How do I make sure that our system does NOT send out emails to people who have a monthly recurring membership?

2) How do I make edits to rules of how membership renewal emails are sent?

Answer (score 2):

Membership renewal notices are controlled by Scheduled Reminders. You can set these up here under 'Administer>Communications>Scheduled Reminders'.

The documentation is here: 
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/scheduled-reminders/#using-scheduled-reminders-for-memberships

With regards to your monthly recurring members you can choose to not send renewal reminders to that particular member type. There is also the following option 'Renewal Reminder (no-auto-renew memberships only)'.

You want to make sure you have the scheduled job 'Send Scheduled Reminders' enabled ('Administer>System Settings>Scheduled Jobs') and a cron job setup to run your scheduled jobs. You can find more info here:
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/

Hope this helps.